# Delphi Postgres stored procedure

Tags: delphi, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am working on **Delphi** application  which deals with **stored procedures**.I created stored procedure for insert statement and it works fine for my application.
Now,I wanted to create the same for select statement.

```
CREATE TYPE list_all_firstname AS ( first_name character varying);  

CREATE FUNCTION select_sp()   
RETURNS SETOF list_all_firstname AS  
$$  
DECLARE  
rec record;  
BEGIN  
  FOR rec IN (SELECT first_name FROM person) LOOP  
  RETURN NEXT rec;  
END LOOP;  
END;  
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The call is:

```
SELECT * FROM select_sp();
```

Till this everything is fine in postgres.I wanted to access this stored procedure in my delphi application.
My code is:

```
 with StoredProc2 do begin
     StoredProcName :='select_sp';
     ExecProc;
     Edit5.Text:=ParamByName('list_all_firstname').AsString ;
    end;
```

But i gets the error saying **"Could not find object"**.How do i access return values of stored procedure in delphi??

Comment: If StoredProc2 is a TDataset descendant, you would have to be using FieldByName. With a TDataset descendant ParamByName is for the parameters that are passed TO the query/storedproc, not the results returned by it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer.**.could not find object** is BDE error...
Next thing is accessing values,no need to use stored procedure component.We can use TQuery as below...:

```
  Query1.SQL.Clear;
  Query1.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM select_sp()');
  Query1.Active := True;

  for i:=0 to Query1.RowsAffected-1 do
          begin
             sval:=Query1.FieldByName('first_name').AsString;
             ShowMessage(sval);
             Query1.Next;
          end;
```